# I'm sure there was an Advanced Fighting Fantasy question somewhere - what happened to it?

Tags: support, tags, deleted-questions

There was a question on RPG.SE about the game system called Advanced Fighting Fantasy. I think it was the only question that used the tag for that game (there was also a tag, probably called [advanced-fighting-fantasy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advanced-fighting-fantasy), but I can't remember exactly).

However, I can find neither the question or the tag. Did they get deleted? Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this the one?: [Is the way my GM is using smite correct?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105519/is-the-way-my-gm-is-using-smite-correct)

I've added back the tag. It likely expired on account of not having a description, so I've added one.

(There are no deleted questions about Advanced Fighting Fantasy.)

Comment: That's the one! Thanks for putting the tag back. It's not a system I use often, but I do play it from time to time (literally months if not years between games).

Comment: Hooray!  Glad I could help.